# Ace-Editor JSON auto format/indent

Tags: javascript, html, json, ace-editor

I have just started using Ace Editor. According to the [doc](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto) ***"the editor supports plain text mode. All other language modes are available as separate modules, loaded on demand..."*** and this is how a JavaScript mode is set `editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");` this only works for highlighting syntax.

In my case I am working with JSON - `editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json")`

**What I am trying to achieve is**

- Display a nicely formatted JSON response

**Problem is**

- Ace Editor can't seem to handle JS objects or JSON on
  `editor.setValue()` it has to be converted to a string

**Question**

- How do I set auto format/indentation on the string which is placed on 
  `<div id="editor"></div>`?

**HTML:**

`<div id="editor"></div>`

**SCRIPT:** *`jsonDoc`* is data from the server

```
$scope.getData = function (jsonDoc) {
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json");
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
  editor.getSession().setTabSize(2);
  editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
  editor.setValue(JSON.stringify(jsonDoc));
};
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To format your JSON string you can use the additional parameters of `JSON.stringify`. Try something like

```
editor.setValue(JSON.stringify(jsonDoc, null, '\t'));
```

The third parameter is used for the indention per level. (Might vary in different implementations). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify for examples.

You can also toggle display options from ace.js file.

Comment: How to do it for other languages?